# Capturing Errors on Spring Integration DSL

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration DSL pipeline connected to a GCP Pubsub and things "work": The data is received and processed as defined in the pipeline, using a collection of `Function` implementations and `.handle()`.

The problem we have (and why I used "work" in quotes) is that, in some handlers, when some of the data isn't found in the companion database, we raise `IllegalStateException`, which forces the data to be reprocessed (along the way, another service may complete the companion database and then function will now work). This exception is never shown anywhere.

We tried to capture the content of `errorHandler`, but we really can't find the proper way of doing it programmatically (no XML).

Our `Function`s have something like this:

```
Record record = recordRepository.findById(incomingData).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Missing information: " + incomingData));
```

This `IllegalStateException` is the one that is not appearing anywhere in the logs.

Also, maybe it's worth mentioning that we have our channels defined as

```
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel cardInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter cardChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("cardInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO);
        adapter.setPayloadType(CardDto.class);
        return adapter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the adapter, but I just looked at the code and it looks like they just nack the message and don't log anything.

You can add an `Advice` to the handler's endpoint to capture and log the exception

```
    .handle(..., e -> e.advice(exceptionLoggingAdvice)


@Bean
public MethodInterceptor exceptionLoggingAdvice() {
    return invocation -> {
        try {
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception thrown) {
            // log it
            throw thrown;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So57224614Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57224614Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(MethodInterceptor myAdvice) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo", endpoint -> endpoint.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .handle("crasher", "crash", endpoint -> endpoint.advice(myAdvice))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInterceptor myAdvice() {
        return invocation -> {
            try {
                return invocation.proceed();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed with " + e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        };
    }


}

@Component
class Crasher {

    public void crash(Message<?> msg) {
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

}
```

and

```
Failed with nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test
```

Comment: `.handle()` doesn't seem to have a signature with an `Advice` argument; `.transform()` does, but it does something different than `.handle()`.

Comment: Related: `.handle()` is a method of `IntegrationFlows` (which is followed by a `.from()`, identifying the channel in which the data is coming from.)

Comment: That is simply not true; all `handle()` methods have an overloaded version that has an addition parameter enabling the configuration of the consumer endpoint. See the edit to my answer. The advice goes on the component that throws the exception.